# How to set up django debugging tool properly?

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm

I am really new with python, django-oscar.

I am trying to set up a debugging tool in pycharm

I went through the documentation at 
http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#internal-ips

I have a few questions which I tried Google but pretty much all gives me the documentation links.

I am using Ubuntu with Python 2.7.6, django-oscar 1.2.1, django 1.9

I followed the documentation up to the last step of the installation "INTERNAL_IPS" but I have no idea where to add that. Is there a specific file to should create or find in order to do add the ip?

Also, after all steps are done, how to I use the debug toolbar?
In the documentation, there's something about `JQUERY_URL` and lots other stuffs which I am pretty much lost in here.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `INTERNAL_IPS` goes into django's `settings.py`. If everything is working as expected you will see debug toolbar appear on your site homepage.

Comment: @serg great it showed up :D thx thx